# How to enter data in firestore using cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

For the document {userID}, I want to create a sub-collection called 'notfications' and set data to it . How do I access the document and set data?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userID}/reports/{reportID}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  // Get an object representing the document
  // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
  const newValue = change.after.data();
  // ...or the previous value before this update
  const previousValue = change.before.data();

  // access a particular field as you would any JS property
    const st1 = newValue.status;
   const st2 = previousValue.status;
   console.log('I am a log entry!' + st1 + " " + st2);
   // Add a new document in collection "cities"


var db = admin.firestore();

    var data = {
    reportid: '4O8UWUPm3yJfOIdTam9S',
    problem: 'It works',
    status: 'status'
};

// Add a new document in collection "cities" with ID 'LA'
var setDoc = db.ref(`/users/${newValue}/notifications/n1`).set(data);

      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

Note that we use `set()` and therefore we have to set the id of the new `notification` doc: here we take the value 'n1', as shown in your question. You could let Firestore auto-generate an ID for you by calling `add()` (on the `notifications` collection) instead of `set()`.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userID}/reports/{reportID}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const previousValue = change.before.data();

    const userID = context.params.userID;

    const st1 = newValue.status;
    const st2 = previousValue.status;
    console.log('I am a log entry!' + st1 + ' ' + st2);

    var data = {
      reportid: '4O8UWUPm3yJfOIdTam9S', //Here, get the value of the reportID by doing: reportid: context.params.reportID,
      problem: 'It works',
      status: 'status'  //Here, if necessary, you could use the value of st1, i.e. the new status
    };


    return db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userID)
      .collection('notifications')
      .doc('n1')
      .set(data)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error writing document: ' + error);
        return false;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Also, in my {userID} document - I have a field called 'token' - how would I access that value?

Comment: If you trigger the function at the level of the user document (i.e. `.document('users/{userID}')`) it will not be triggered when you modify a report document. So you have two solutions, IMHO: 1/ Query the parent doc in the Cloud Function (`const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(userID); docRef.get()....`). You would need to chain the promises as the `get()` method is asynchronous. 2/ Duplicate the data in the report document, i.e. when creating the report document include in the report data the value of the token of the parent user document.